# Unity delivers pictures to Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an `AR glasses` project. The glasses are connected to `Android mobile phones`, and then displayed on the glasses through `two screens`. For some reason, I need to talk about `unity's camera` rendering pictures, passing them to `Android`, and then `Android displays` them on `AR glasses`. Is there any way to quickly transfer pictures from unity to Android?

```
 if (Display.displays.Length > 1)
    {
        camera.SetTargetBuffers(Display.displays[1].colorBuffer, Display.displays[1].depthBuffer);
        camera.enabled = true;
    }
```

This is the method of unity dual screen display, but it can't use WiFi display on some mobile phones. When WiFi display is turned on in some mobile phones, display. Displays. Length = = 1

I know how to use byte array, but the efficiency will be very low

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean by "transfer to Android". Your unity app, I assume, is executing on the same Android device, so you can save your image in device gallery and then show it in some other app or by simple opening it in the gallery app. There are a plenty of android native plugins for unity that allows you to save a texture in gallery.

Comment: I hope to transfer unity's rendered image to Android code for use. It is not a single image, but a real-time image, similar to a video stream